# SWF is not displayed as specified in HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have a FlashBuilder project for which I want to set the displayed size (in browser) only via the html file. I don't want to hardcode the size of the swf in the flash code.
Also I need to provide several parameters with flash vars.
My html is a modified version of the standard html code generated by FlashBuilder. I try to set the size of the swf in JavaScript and using a container div. So I have the following html code to display the swf:

```
<html>   
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body {
            height:100%;
        }
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:auto;
            text-align:center;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        object:focus {
            outline:none;
        }
        #flashContent {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens
    with two hyphens -->
    <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
    <!-- END Browser History required section -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var swfVersionStr = "11.1.0";
        // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        var attributes = {};
        flashvars.json = "some json file.json";
        flashvars.width = "900";
        flashvars.height = "480";
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.wmode = "direct";
        attributes.id = "Main";
        attributes.name = "Main";
        attributes.align = "left";
        swfobject.embedSWF("Main.swf", "flashContent", "100%", "100%",
        swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
        flashvars, params, attributes);
        // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="display:block;text-align:left;width:900px; height:480px; position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px">
        <div id="flashContent">
            <p>To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 11.1.0 or greater
                is installed.</p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");
                document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>");
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following in my flash main method:

```
public function Main(){

    swfWidth = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.width;
    swfHeight = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.height;
    swfFrameRate = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.framerate;

    json = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.json;
    loadJsonFile(json); 

    stage.frameRate = swfFrameRate;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    view = new View3D();
    view.width = swfWidth;
    view.height = swfHeight;
    camera = view.camera; 
    cameraController = new HoverController(camera, null, 150, 10, 10);
    this.addChild(view); 
}
```

However, when I open this in browser the displayed size does not match the size given in the hmtl (with the above code it results in about 700x430 px).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any way you could post a link to this running will probably be easier to diagnose/offer a solution?

Comment: You may want to try renaming those flashvars to something that isn't already a property - like 'movie_width' and 'movie_height'. It's possible they are getting passed in before the object is sized, but that you are reading the actual width/height of the object rather than the values you are passing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix it. 
The problem was the Main.html and index.template.html created by Flashbuilder (and wich is not easy to revise, as it is very complex and more detailed than actually needed.

I created a new .html file with the help of this generator:
http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html

.. and now the stage is set as provided by the flashVars.

This is how my Main looks like now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("Main", "11.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="850" height="480" id="Main">
            <param name="movie" value="Main.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="best" />
            <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
            <param name="salign" value="tl" />
            <param name="wmode" value="direct" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#cccccc" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="allownetworking" value="all" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="json=../somejsonFile.json&amp;width=850&amp;height=480&framerate=60" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Main.swf" width="850" height="480">
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="salign" value="tl" />
                <param name="wmode" value="direct" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#cccccc" />
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <param name="allownetworking" value="all" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="json=../somejsonFilejson&amp;width=850&amp;height=480&framerate=60" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```